# Неверно берутся данные из базы данных

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

У меня есть код для получения карточек раз в 4 часа. Если пользователь получил карты 2023-14-10 16:26:48, то до 2023-14-10 20:26:48 он не сможет получить карточки, но если пользователь попробует получить их 2023-15-10 с 16:26:48 до 20:26:48 он также не сможет получить карточку, хотя прошли уже сутки с момента получения карточки. Что может быть не так?

```py
from cards import *


def get_card(message):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    last_command_use_time = \
        cur.execute('SELECT get_card_cd FROM users WHERE user_id={}'.format(message.chat.id)).fetchone()[0]
    x = datetime.datetime.strptime(last_command_use_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    p = list(itertools.accumulate([0.01, 0.005, 0.015, 0.05, 0.07, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.4]))
    n = bisect.bisect(p, random.random())
    if not last_command_use_time or (datetime.datetime.now() - x).seconds / 14400 > 1:
        cur.execute('UPDATE users SET get_card_cd=? WHERE user_id=?', (datetime.datetime.now(), message.chat.id))
        conn.commit()
        if n == 0:
            # print("1%")
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Вам выпала - ❓Secret Cards❓')
        elif n == 1:
            # print("0,5%")
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Вам выпала -  Single ')
        elif n == 2:
            # print("1,5%")
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Вам выпала - ⬛️ Limited Edition ⬛️')
        elif n == 3:
            # print("5%")
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Вам выпала -  Легендарная ')
        elif n == 4:
            # print("7%")
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Вам выпала -  Ультра редкая ')
        elif n == 5:
            # print("10%")
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Вам выпала -  Супер редкая ')
        elif n == 6:
            # print("15%")
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Вам выпала -  Редкая ')
        elif n == 7:
            # print("20%")
            unusual(message)
        elif n == 8:
            print("40%")
            regural(message)
        else:
            print('Error')
    else:
        seconds = (x - datetime.datetime.now()).seconds - 72000
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Следующая попытка будет доступна через<i>{convert(seconds)}</i>',
                         parse_mode='Html')

    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

```py
def convert(seconds):
    min, sec = divmod(seconds, 60)
    hour, min = divmod(min, 60)
    day = 0
    if hour >= 24:
        day = hour // 24
        hour = hour % 24
    if day != 0:
        day = str(day) + ' дней,'
    else:
        day = ''
    if hour != 0:
        hour = str(hour) + ' ч'
    else:
        hour = ''
    if min != 0:
        min = str(min) + ' мин'
    else:
        min = ''

    return f'{day} {hour} {min}'
```

Comment: А у вас точно одна карточка у пользователя? И уберите `format` из `SELECT` запроса, сделайте так же подстановку параметра как в `UPDATE`. А вообще подключите логирование и логируйте все значения переменных и куда пошло ветвление. Может что-то понятнее будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в этом выражении выводится значение меньше 1 если прошло больше суток, это связано с тем что `seconds` не учитывает дни

```py
(datetime.datetime.now() - x).seconds / 14400 > 1:
```

Попробуйте применить `total_seconds()` вместо `seconds` , разница во времени должна конвертироваться в секунды и делиться на 4 часа

```py
if not last_command_use_time or (datetime.datetime.now() - x).total_seconds() / 14400 > 1:
```

Comment: О, точно, слона то я и не заметил, а тут всё просто.